# Pass arguments following make to variables in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a piece of `makefile` to generate `.pdf`, `.ps`, `.dvi` from `.tex`:

```
...
$(FILE).pdf: $(FILE).tex $(SRC) $(DEPS)
    latex $(FILE).tex && \
    bibtex --min-crossrefs=500 $(FILE) && \
    latex $(FILE).tex && \
    latex $(FILE).tex && \
    dvips $(FILE).dvi -o $(FILE).ps && \
    ps2pdf $(FILE).ps $(FILE).pdf
...
```

I would like to get `$(FILE)` directly from the command line, as the first argument following `make`. For instance, `make paper` compiles `paper.tex` and generates `paper.pdf`. Also, I don't want to permit `make` or `make all` as a command, where no file name is specified.

Could anyone tell me how to pass the first argument following `make` to `$(FILE)`?

Comment: What if you want to generate `all.pdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, depending on exactly what behavior you want. (And I'm not sure I entirely understand your command-- I don't think there's any reason to have it as one wrapped line-- but never mind.)

**If you want to allow only targets from a list known beforehand:**

```
FILES = scissors paper rock

$(FILES): % : %.tex $(SRC) $(DEPS)
    latex $*.tex && \
    ...
```

**If you want to allow only targets for which `.tex` files exist:**

```
% : %.tex $(SRC) $(DEPS)
    latex $*.tex && \
    ...
```

Now for what to do about unwanted targets. **If a warning is enough:**

```
all:
    @echo $@ is not a valid target

(real rule)

%:
    @echo $@ is not a valid target
```

**If you want Make to abort entirely,** I think it's possible but I'll have to think it over some more...

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `make` works.  Perhaps you want to use a shell script which accepts a parameter, validates it, and invokes `make` with your Makefile, passing the file in as a `make` variable; that is, something like

```
make -f tex.mk FILE="$validated_filename"
```